# Scope issues keep getting my undefined - simple JavaScript function with loop and if statement

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

Update:
I was able to get true and false indications for the users I want to select but thus far I am unable to actually put their IDs in an array. The latest code:

cInfo is an object with {key1: array, key2: 'user'}
where array is an array of objects
where 'name' is a key inside each object in each array

```
var theAnswer = [];
var answer = function() {
     for(var c = 0; c < cInfo.array.length; c++)
        var pitched = _.some(_.map(cInfo.array[c], function(n) {return n.name == Name}))
     if (pitched)
         theAnswer.push(cInfo.user[c]);
         return theAnswer;
}
```

console.log(cInfo.user) returns a user but within the function it remains undefined.

END OF UPDATE

---

I keep getting undefined from this code. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my closures but if I really knew I wouldn't be posting this:

`cComplete` is an array of objects with key fields including name and user.

```
var answer = function() {
    var c = cComplete.length
    while (c--) {
        var theAnswer = [];
        if (cComplete[c].name == Name) {
            theAnswer.push(cComplete[c].user);

        }
    }
    return theAnswer
}
console.log(answer());
```

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. I have added data in cComplete and Name as below. ..
var cComplete = [{name:'a',user:'ua'},{name:'b',user:'ub'}]
var Name = 'a'

Comment: hilarious, everyone can run my code but me?!? Could it be something else in my environmentment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring and initializing `theAnswer` before the loop, because right now its scope is limited to the loop. Not only that, but currently every time the loop iterates, your array is reset, so its pretty much useless except for the last element anyway. Initializing prior to the loop will fix both these issues.

Hope this helps, happy coding.

Comment: in javascript , loop does not create scope.

Comment: Brad, I guess that helped, it went from providing me undefined results to providing the empty arrays. It should provide two users.

Comment: @Partha, Really? when I close off the loop the results I get are different in the console.log then when I don't

Comment: I do apologize for the mistake about scope and loops, I don't code very much in JavaScript at the moment. Glad I could help somewhat.